# Unable to pickup file from SDCARD in Oreo

Tags: android

I am New in Android, Working on one functionality in which I have to pick up a file from internal storage and SDCARD. I have implemented some code. With the help of below code, I am able to pick up or select a file from SDcard and internal storage in the Android pie version(9 API level 28) and Android Nougat version(7) but I am not able to get pdf file in from SDCARD in Android Oreo(8 api level 26) version and for Marshmallow it is unable to select file from internal as well as SDCARD. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Same code working for one not working for another. There is any universal way to access files(pdf and images).Thanks in advance

Implemented Code Below

```
    private void SelectFileFromGallery(){
              Intent intent = new Intent();
                        String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
                        intent.setType("*/*");
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_file)), SELECT_FILE);
            }

            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                         if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                            onSelectFileFromGalleryResult(data);
                            isUpdated = true;

                    } else if (requestCode == 11) {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                }

        private void onSelectFileFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
                try {
                    InputStream is;

                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

                    String file= AndroidUtilities.getFilePath(selectedImageUri);
                    File imageFile = new File(file);
                    Log.d("File Path",imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        // Here I am Compressing the file to store
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    public static String getFilePath(final Uri uri) {

            String filePath="";
            try {
               final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
                if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(MyApp.applicationContext, uri)) {
                    if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        final  String type=split[0];
                         String storageDefinition;


    //                    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
    //                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
    //                    } else {
    //
    //                        if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()){
    //                            storageDefinition = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    //
    //                        } else{
    //                            storageDefinition = "SECONDARY_STORAGE";
    //                        }
    //
    //                        return System.getenv(storageDefinition) + "/" + split[1];
    //                    }

                        if("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){
                        if (split.length > 1) {
                            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                        } else {
                            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                        }
                        // This is for checking SD Card
                    }
                        else if ("home".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/documents/" + split[1];
                        }
                        else {

                            return "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");

                    }

                    } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                        String fileName = getFileName(MyApp.applicationContext, uri);
                        final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                        if(fileName!=null){
                            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Download/"+fileName;
                        }

                        if (id != null && id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                            return id.substring(4);
                        }

                        String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                                "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/my_downloads",
                                "content://downloads/all_downloads",

                        };

    //                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefixesToTry), Long.valueOf(id));
    //                    return getDataColumn(MyApp.applicationContext, contentUri, null, null);
                        for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
                            try {
                                String path = getDataColumn(MyApp.applicationContext, contentUri, null, null);
                                if (path != null) {
                                    return path;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {}
                        }

    //                    File cacheDir = getDocumentCacheDir(MyApp.applicationContext);
    //                    File file = generateFileName(fileName, cacheDir);
    //                    String destinationPath = null;
    //                    if (file != null) {
    //                        destinationPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    //                        saveFileFromUri(MyApp.applicationContext, uri, destinationPath);
    //                    }

    //                    return destinationPath;

                    } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)||isMediaStorage(uri)) {
                        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                        final String type = split[0];

                        Uri contentUri = null;
                        switch (type) {
                            case "image":
                                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                                break;
                            case "video":
                                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                                break;
                            case "audio":
                                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                                break;
                        }

                        final String selection = "_id=?";
                        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                                split[1]
                        };

                        return getDataColumn(MyApp.applicationContext, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                    }
                } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                    return getDataColumn(MyApp.applicationContext, uri, null, null);
                } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                    return uri.getPath();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return null;

        }

 private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                String value = cursor.getString(column_index);
                if (value.startsWith("content://") || !value.startsWith("/") && !value.startsWith("file://")) {
                    return null;
                }
                return value;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaStorage(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`. Remove that line. It makes no sense. You cannot grant anything as you are not the boss.

Comment: So the user cannor select a file and onActivityResult is not triggered. Is that what you say?

Comment: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` You still have that while you also put mime type `"*/*"`. That makes no sense.

Comment: You have asked this all before. But the first time you complained you could not pick a pdf file. And now you complain you cannot pick from sd card but still mention pdf. It is pretty unclear what your real problem is.

Comment: @blackapps-In Oreo whenever I try to select the file from SDCARD, getFilePath() method returns some path that path is unable to locate the file in the Oreo android version but in Nougat and pie it is able to locate.

Comment: `and for Marshmallow it is unable to select file from internal as well as SDCARD.` Not true! The user can select a file.

Comment: @Blackapps Yes it is true I am not able to select file from internal as well as from sd card in marshmallow.

Comment: @blackapps-could you suggest the sensefull method to get right path from Uri.

Comment: `Yes it is true I am not able to select file from internal as well as from sd card in marshmallow. ` Sorry. I do not believe that. The user can select a file and onActivityResult will be triggered.

Comment: @blackapps okk,so suggest me a universal way that will work on all android version>23

Comment: ??? A universal way for what? It looks as if you do not understand what i'm trying to tell you.

Comment: What this means 'YOU WILL NOT TRY TO GET A PATH FROM URI'